# Import ES Module

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a standalone node.js project. The steps I followed are -

1. Created a new directory and initialised it with `npm init`.
2. Installed the new module for `node-fetch`.
3. Trying to import the fetch module using `const fetch = require("node-fetch");` statement.

Getting the following error -

`const fetch = require("node-fetch");`

`Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/jatin/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js from /Users/jatin/Desktop/test-app/index.js not supported. Instead change the require of /Users/jatin/Desktop/test-app/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js in /Users/jatin/Desktop/test-app/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules. at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jatin/Desktop/test-app/index.js:2:15) { code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' }`

The node version I have on my machine is - v16.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an ES module import instead of `require`.

```js
import * as fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

You could also use a dynamic import, as the error message states.

```js
const fetch = import('node-fetch');
```